# Deleting an array element (C#)

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete an int array element at the user input index and value (means replacing array element by the next one) so it is doing but in output it gives me the element twice example input array is : 1 2 3 4 5 6 and user says to delete 3rd element at 3 index then output is :1 2 4 4 5 6 what is the solution plz.Without using any function or library.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter The Length Of Linear Array");
int length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] LinearArr = new int[length + 2];
Console.WriteLine("Maximum Number Of Inputs : {0}", length);


for (int i = 1; i < LinearArr.Length - 1; i++)
{
    LinearArr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine("What Number You Want To Delete And At What Index");
int InsertNum2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int k2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Number :{0} And Index :{1}",InsertNum2,k2);

InsertNum2 = LinearArr[k2];
for (int i = k2; i < LinearArr.Length-1; i++)
{
    LinearArr[k2] = LinearArr[k2 + 1];


}
length = length - 1;
for (int i = 1; i < LinearArr.Length-1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(LinearArr[i]);
}
//Input  :1 2 3 4 5 6
//output :1 2 4 4 5 6
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the problem exactly? Your code works as you expected.

Comment: Just use a `List<T>` instead of an array. It has a `Remove` function.

Comment: its impossible to tell if you want the element repeated or not.  Can you clarify your problem?

Comment: when i want to delete first and last element it works it gives output as i want like this input array : 1 2 3 4 5 6 output 1 2 3 4 5 but but for all other indexes except first and last it is not giving the output as i want like this input array:1 2 3 4 5 6 output :1 3 3 4 5 6 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem of your code is you're using `k2` in: `LinearArr[k2] = LinearArr[k2 + 1];`, you should use `i` instead. And I think your approach is not a good approach, maybe the following approach will fit your requirement:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter The Length Of Linear Array");
int length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] LinearArr = new int[length + 2];
Console.WriteLine("Maximum Number Of Inputs : {0}", length);


for (int i = 1; i < LinearArr.Length - 1; i++)
{
    LinearArr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine("What Number You Want To Delete And At What Index");
int InsertNum2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int k2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Number :{0} And Index :{1}",InsertNum2,k2);

//create a new array with length = LinearArray - 1
int[] newArray = new int[LinearArray.Length - 1];
int currentIndex = 0;

InsertNum2 = LinearArr[k2];
for (int i = 0; i < LinearArr.Length; i++)
{
    //if i == index want to delete, ignore
    if(i != k2) 
    {
        newArray[currentIndex] = LinearArray[i];
        currentIndex++;
    }
}
length = length - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length-1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(newArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant remove an item from the middle of the array at runtime. Your best option is converting your array to list.

```
        var a = new[] { "A", "B", "C" }.ToList();
        a.RemoveAt(1);
        foreach (var x in a)
            Console.WriteLine(x);
```

If for some reason you can't use a list instead of array, you can move elements one by one and resize the array at last.

```
        var a = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
        for (var i = 1; i < a.Length - 1; i++)
            a[i] = a[i + 1];
        Array.Resize(ref a, a.Length - 1);
        foreach (var x in a)
            Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array to a list, remove the element and convert the list back to array.

```
var numList = LinearArr.ToList();
numList.Remove(k2);
LinearArr = numList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the index `i` instead of `k2`

```
for (int i = k2; i < LinearArr.Length - 1; i++)
    LinearArr[i] = LinearArr[i + 1];
}
```

(`k2` does not change)

Comment: If you don't resize the array, it will contain: 1 2 4 5 6 6

Comment: @Biri: This is just a code fragment, explaining where the error is. It is not the complete solution. Of course `length = length - 1;` will still have to be called (I would however just write `length--;`)

Comment: Ok, just my 2 cents. I got downvotes for not providing the complete solution only the parts in question. :-)

Comment: There's no point in repeating 30 lines of the OP's code if only one line has changed.

Comment: From my point of view the original code has two problems. But you are right, he asked only for the output correction.

Comment: His code has many problems: Inconsistent use of `LinearArr.Length` and `length`. Unused variables (`InsertNum2` is assigned a value, but not used later). Strange variable names (there is a `k2`, where is `k1`?). Violation of .NET naming conventions. Mix of GUI-logic and business-logic. Why initialize `LinearArr`  with `length + 2`? ...